# How to implements StackScrollView like Twitter app for iPad on android?

Tags: android-layout, android-widget

How to implements StackScrollView like Twitter app for iPad on android? I have on idea how to create StackScrollView on android. Thanks in advance for any help!

Twitter for Apple iPad app review: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RIJTXNfGHuM

Answer (score 1):

you can get it at https://github.com/raweng/Android-StackScrollview